# Is it possible to track search phrases in Google Play that lead to install?

Tags: google-analytics, google-play, google-analytics-firebase

I want to understand what people search in Google Play to find and install our app.

Is it possible to track search phrases/keywords in Google Play that lead to install?

Can google analytics do that?

Answer (score 2):

No Google Analytics can't do that.

I'm not familiar with which reports Google Play makes available to app developers but I believe that's the only possible source of this kinds of data. So I'd check your Developers page for that.

Maybe 3rd parties have products that give you that kind of data but these would be guesses/estimates at best.